# How to connect disjointed lines or edges in images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, line, edge-detection, binary-image

I am currently working on lines extraction from a binary image. I initially performed a few image processing steps including threshold segmentation and obtained the following binary image.

[image: Input sample image]

As can be seen in the binary image the lines are splitted or broken. And I wanted to join the broken line as shown in the image below marked in red. I marked the red line manually for a demonstration.

[image: as shown in the sample]

FYI, I used the following code to perform the preprocessing.

```
img = cv2.imread('original_image.jpg')  # loading image 
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # coverting to gray scale
median_filter = cv2.medianBlur (gray_image, ksize = 5) # median filtering 

th, thresh = cv2.threshold (median_filter, median_filter.mean(), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # theshold segmentation

# small dots and noise removing 
nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
areas = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
result = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)
min_size = 150 
for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if areas[i] >= min_size:   #keep
        result[labels == i + 1] = 255

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(30,20))
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[0].set_title('Original image')

ax[1].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax[1].set_title('preprocessed image')
```

I would really appreciate it if you have any suggestions or steps on how to connect the lines? Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: More importantly than code, can we see the original image ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following sequence of methods I was able to get a rough approximation. It is a very simple solution and might not work for all cases.

**1. Morphological operations**

To merge neighboring lines perform morphological (dilation) operations on the binary image.

```py
img = cv2.imread('image_path', 0)     # grayscale image
img1 = cv2.imread('image_path', 1)    # color image

th = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (19, 19))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
```

[image]

**2. Finding contours and extreme points**

1. My idea now is to find contours.
2. Then find the extreme points of each contour.
3. Finally find the closest distance among these extreme points between neighboring contours. And draw a line between them.

```py
cnts1 = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

cnts = cnts1[0]     # storing contours in a variable
```

Lets take a quick detour to visualize where these extreme points are present:

```py
# visualize extreme points for each contour
for c in cnts:
    left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    right = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    bottom = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

    # Draw dots onto image
    cv2.circle(img1, left, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, right, 8, (0, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, top, 8, (255, 50, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(img1, bottom, 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)
```

(***Note:*** The extreme points points are based of contours from morphological operations, but drawn on the original image)

[image]

**3. Finding closest distances between neighboring contours**

Sorry for the many loops.

1. First, iterate through every contour (split line) in the image.
2. Find the extreme points for them. Extreme points mean top-most, bottom-most, right-most and left-most points based on its respective bounding box.
3. Compare the distance between every extreme point of a contour with those of every other contour. And draw a line between points with the least distance.

```py
for i in range(len(cnts)):

    min_dist = max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

    cl = []
    
    ci = cnts[i]
    ci_left = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    ci_right = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    ci_top = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    ci_bottom = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
    ci_list = [ci_bottom, ci_left, ci_right, ci_top]
    
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cnts)):
        cj = cnts[j]
        cj_left = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cj_right = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        cj_top = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cj_bottom = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        cj_list = [cj_bottom, cj_left, cj_right, cj_top]
        
        for pt1 in ci_list:
            for pt2 in cj_list:
                dist = int(np.linalg.norm(np.array(pt1) - np.array(pt2)))     #dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist = dist             
                    cl = []
                    cl.append([pt1, pt2, min_dist])
    if len(cl) > 0:
        cv2.line(img1, cl[0][0], cl[0][1], (255, 255, 255), thickness = 5)
```

[image]

**4. Post-processing**

Since the final output is not perfect, you can perform additional morphology operations and then skeletonize it.